# MongoClient doesnt trigger callback in case of error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
        MongoClient.connect(this._config.connectionString, {
          useNewUrlParser: true,
          useUnifiedTopology: true,
        }, (err, db) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(`error on connect : ${err}`);
            return console.dir(err);
          }
          console.log('We are connected');
          this._client = db;

        });
```

This piece helps me connect to mongodb running locally, and works fine when DBserver is up and running. But if i stop db server and then try to execute this...it doesnt call the call back. Is there a way i can get call back in case of DB is down or not reachable?

below code doesnt get call back, in case of future DB errors.

```
this._client.on('error', args => this.onError(args));
```

Because of this issue of not getting call backs, in case of any severe errors...my server goes down without showing any error.

Comment: I get callbacks in case of successful connection.

Comment: What happens when you add a `.catch(err => { console.log(err); })` at the end of your await statement after the last occurence of `});` ?

Comment: there is no exception thrown...next statements get executed normally. And this connect method returns void, so i cannot put .catch()

Comment: I wonder why you are using both callback and await !

Comment: i know i shouldnt. Out of desperation...was trying lots of things randomly.

Comment: Strange!! I just copied your code and run in my machine. It is executing the callback with errors as expected.

Comment: Oh damn, now its more complicated! I'm working on a huge codebase and new to node. Is there anything i'm missing at project level configuration?

And, if you stop db server....your app gets notified?

Comment: I don't think you need some special configuration. It is straight forward. Import `MongoClient` and call the `connect()` and you are good to go. Are you using latest version of mongo driver? I've used latest driver and yes my server is stopped.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: Here is my code. https://pastebin.com/0Mzr3e3X

Comment: Thanks. but i dont get it, once you start your app and mongodb, later if you kill mongo service but your node app is still running...where do you get call back?

Comment: nevermind, got it working.